# React Bootstrap - Close NavDropdown on route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I'm using `<NavDropdown>` ([link to docs](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/navs/#nav-dropdown-props)) in a `<Nav>` component and it works great.  The problem I have is that I can't close an open dropdown on route change.  Here's an example of the code:

```
const menuItems = {
  "menu item": {
    title: "Menu Title",
    links: [
      {
        text: "Link Text",
        route: "/route-to-page"
      },
      {
        text: "Link Text 2",
        route: "/route-to-page-2"
      }
    ]
  }
};

<Nav>
  {menuItems.map((item) => (
    <NavDropdown title={Menu[item].title}>
      .. Some menu items...
    </NavDropdown>
  )}
</Nav>
```

I would like to be able to add an `onClick` handler to links that closes any open dropdowns, but I can't see an effective way to do this.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I have got this to work as follows:

```
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

<NavDropdown title="Maintenance" id="navigation-dropdown">
  <NavDropdown.Item to="/categories" as={Link}>Categories</NavDropdown.Item>
  <NavDropdown.Item to="/account-types" as={Link}>Account Types</NavDropdown.Item>
</NavDropdown>
```

It doesn't restart the app when an item is selected and the menu closes. You could populate the items programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean you cant ? of-curse you can

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

<Nav.Link as="a" to="/" onClick={e=> {
 // close modal
}}>
Link
</Nav.Link>
```

Comment: But this would reload the page as href's bypass the router?  It would work, but I'd rather not force a refresh of the app each time.

Comment: if so why dont you just use the `<Link />`component that comes with `react-router-dom`

Comment: That's what I am using.  Using this does not close the dropdown and there isn't anything specifically available to that component to do it.  See my fix above for my workaround - closest I could get but assuming there's a better way.

Comment: use the onBlur event

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution for this, but it is a bit clunky.  Here goes.

First of all, we create an object in state.

```
    const resetMenu = {
        dropdown1: false,
        dropdwon2: false,
        // etc.
    };
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState({ ...resetMenu });
```

`resetMenu` could be generated dynamically.

We can then use `react-router-dom`'s `useLocation` to watch for route changes.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const location = useLocation();
```

Then we can use React `useEffect` hook to listen out for changes to that location and set values in our `menu` state to false.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setMenu({...resetMenu});
  }
}, [location]);
```

Finally, we can use the `show` prop to control whether the dropdown is visible, and an `onClick` on the toggle to change the value in `menu` state.

```
<Nav>
  {menuItems.map((item) => (
    <NavDropdown 
      title={menu[item].title}
      show={menu[item]}
      onClick={() =>
        setMenu((prevState) => ({
            ...resetMenu,
            [item]: !prevState[item],
        }))
    >
      .. Some menu items...
    </NavDropdown>
  )}
</Nav>
```

I hope that helps someone else with this same problem.